# Customizing [Success] Messages in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have found many articles about customizing error messages in asp.net mvc.

What I would like to know is how to show a success message.

For example, when I enter a valid email address I would show that the data entered has passed the validation by either changing the style of the control in which it was entered or providing a successful validation message.

All the asp.net mvc samples I have see so far explain how to display or customize error messages after failing validation.

I would like to know how to show a success message when the validation succeeds.

Does anyone know how to do this or know of a link/resource that can show me how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the unobtrusive clientside validation setting in asp.net mvc3.

You can see how to do this [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/07/13/overriding-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-settings-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)

The most important code in from the url is:

```
    $(function() {
        var settngs = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
        var oldErrorFunction = settngs.errorPlacement;
        var oldSucessFunction = settngs.success;
        settngs.errorPlacement = function (error, inputElement) {
            //Do something here
            oldErrorFunction(error, inputElement);
        }
        settngs.success = function (error) {
            //Do something here
            oldSucessFunction(error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Vote the answer up if it was useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Its a good idea to show success message. You can display a success message by applying jquery on view's button click where you are submitting data.